# Returning only one record per id group? distinct?

Tags: ruby-on-rails

I have a Suppliers, Prices, Items table. Prices join the suppliers to prices.
Prices has a column called 'item_code'.

Given a particulate item_id I want a list of the suppliers who have a price for the item with the latest item_code.

I have it working but I get the same supplier multiple times id if they have multiple price records.

I have tried group(:id) but it tells me I have to add :item_code to the group and if i do that it gives me multiple records for the same supplier_id....

This is what I came up with so far (works but returns multiples of the same supplier):

```
Supplier.joins(:prices).where(prices: {item_id: 1}).where.not(prices: {item_code: nil}).order('prices.created_at DESC').pluck(:id, :item_code)
```

Comment: Could you elaborate on the expected output? 
Are you expecting supplier_id, and an array of the item_codes? 
`[{id: [item_code_1, item_code_2, item_code_3]}]`

Comment: `Price.where(item_id: 1).select(:supplier_id).distinct` ?

Comment: I want an array of suppliers and the item_code of their latest price if that makes sense? Thank you again!